# How to set calendar position when it is on extreme right in handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I am having table in which date column is in extreme right position.

When i click on it i can't see whole calendar.

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: getCarData(),
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Model', 'Registration test', 'Price', 'Registration date'],
    columns: [
      {
        type: 'autocomplete',
        source: ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Chrysler', 'Citroen', 'Mercedes', 'Nissan', 'Opel', 'Suzuki', 'Toyota', 'Volvo'],
        strict: false
      },
      {
        // 2nd cell is simple text, no special options here
      },
      {
        type: 'text'
      },
      {
        type: 'numeric',
        format: '$ 0,0.00'
      },
      {
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        correctFormat: true,
        defaultDate: '01/01/1900'
      }
    ]
  });
```

Please check the js fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hemantmalpote/Lc8r4n6z/

Comment: Same issue :(. Mine scrolls horizontally to the left when it's in edit mode. If not then the calendar is way too far. There seems to be some issue in positioning it as the last column.